# Почему в int переменной странное число?

Tags: c

Почему переменная `t` выводит на экран не то?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int a[7];

void vvoda(){
    puts("Puts values for a array");
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
}

void suma(){
    int t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        t += a[i];
        t = t/7;
        printf("%i\n", &t);
    }
    printf("Average of a array is %i", &t);
}

main(void){
    vvoda();
    suma();
}
```

Вот что выдает консоль:

> ```
> Puts values for a array
> 4
> 5
> 45
> 4
> 54
> 5
> 4
> 2293272
> 2293272
> 2293272
> 2293272
> 2293272
> 2293272
> 2293272
> 2293272
> Average of a array is 2293272
> --------------------------------
> Proccess exited after 2.143 seconds with return value 0
> Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
> ```

Comment: а зачем вы используете оператор `&` перед `t`?

Comment: @Grundy Видимо для того что бы показать адрес переменной, правда не ясно чем адрес кажется странным :)

Comment: @Mike, мне кажется здесь просто по аналогии со scanf сделали, даже не знаю чего минусуют

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас не инициализирована локальная переменная `t`

```
void suma(){
    int t;
    ^^^^^^
```

Во-вторых, если вы используете выражение `t = t/7;`, то логично было бы объявить эту переменную, как число с плавающей запятой, например, имеющую тип `double`. Иначе у вас будет отбрасывание дробной части, то есть будет иметь место целочисленное деление. Например, при `t` равным 4 выражение `t/7` будет равно `0`.

И, в-третьих, в данных предложениях вывода

```
printf("%i\n", &t);
              ^^^^

printf("Average of a array is %i", &t);
                                   ^^^^
```

вы должны использовать саму переменную, а не указатель на нее.

```
printf("%i\n", t);
printf("Average of a array is %i", t);
```

Имейте в виду, что согласно стандарту C функция main без параметров должна иметь объявление

```
int main( void )
^^^
```

Также вместо магического числа 7 было бы лучше ввести именованную константу, как, например,

```
#define N 7
```

и использовать это имя вместо числа.

Например

```
#define N 7

int a[N];

void vvoda(){
    puts("Puts values for a array");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
    }
}
// и т.д.
```

Также не было никакой необходимости объявлять массив `a` глобальным.

Заголовок `<math.h>` можно исключить из программы, так как ни одно определение из этого заголовка не используется.

Comment: а компилятор сам не обнулит? не инициализированную.

Comment: нет, не обнулит

Comment: @Grundy Компилятор обнуляет только переменные, имеющие статическое время жизни.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что переменная `t` лежит на стеке. Переменные, которые лежат на стеке "инициализируются" "мусором". Нужно сделать так:

```
int t = 0;
```

А вместо

```
printf("%i\n", &t);
```

написать

```
printf("%d\n", t);
```

Comment: тогда почему значение не меняется в цикле? :)

Comment: printf("%d\n", t);

Comment: что должна была доказывать эта строчка?

Comment: вместо "printf("%i\n", &t);" написать "printf("%d\n", t);"

Comment: я думаю стоит добавить это в ответ :)